# cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native after deploying rails app to a new Debian server

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've started our deployment process to a production server based on Debian Squeeze.
We've been developing this Rails application in a MacOS.

- Rails is version 3.2.8
- Ruby is version 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

We have installed rvm since the beggining and the application works flawlessly in my computer.

In order to understand what would be required and then make a script with Capistrano, I started with:

- Installed successfully Ruby.
- Installed successfully Rails.
- Installed SQLite3. (I won't use it in production)
- Installed successfully RVM.
- Copied the whole app directory and ran **bundle install** inside it.

Then, ran **rake about** just to make sure that everything is ok getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in        `require'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in   `rescue in <top (required)>'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/root/rails_app/depot/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/root/rails_app/depot/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/root/rails_app/depot/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake- 0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/root/rails_app/depot/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Every other command like, *rails server* or *rails console* shows the same error.

Comment: did you try [this(click me)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604049/no-such-file-to-load-sqlite3-sqlite3-native)?

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232986/error-with-new-rails-3-2-8-project-require-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3)

Comment: Bahdan 
I did the first one yesterday.
The last one requires that I use another environment manager (rbenv) rather than RVM which I will consider just as the last resort.

Comment: **Solution**
I deleted the vendor/bundle directory and ran again bundle install.
Afterwards, I installed execJs (gem install execJs) and changed Gemfile uncommenting the line that loads it.
Finally, I ran:
* bundle install --no-deployment